# Fix Android Library References

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

For some reason in Eclipse my "Referenced Libraries" is showing up as "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES" this is causing me major problems.  I have removed the SKD and eclipse and re installed them get the same thing.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is actually not an Android SDK problem but rather an Eclipse issue in which a reference has been ruined.  To solve this just delete the .metadata folder from your project work space then import your projects back into Eclipse.